# "Looks more genuine than me/I writing"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, personal-pronouns, comparisons

In the following sentence, which is more appropriate — *I* or *me*, and why?

> Sending separate mails will look more genuine than me/I writing on behalf of everyone.

Comment: Neither. "... than **my** writing on behalf of everyone."

Comment: Check this http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/i-or-me          I would suggest sending separate mails will look more genuine than my writing a mail on behalf of everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Writing* in your sentence is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund). A gerund is an non-finite form of a verb, and as such it does not permit an actual subject (just like participles and infinitives do not permit true subjects).

However, as with infinitives, there are ways to express the subject role in connection with a gerund. With infinitives, we use *for* (subject in italics, infinitive in bold):

> It is difficult *for me* **to do** it.

A gerund is, traditionally speaking, a *nominal* form, i.e., it resembles a noun. Therefore, many prescriptivists claim that its subject should be expressed in the same way that the ‘subject’ (i.e., owner) of a regular noun is—using the possessive (subject in italics, gerund in bold):

> He doesn’t like *my* **singing** so loudly all the time.
>   *Peter’s* **taking** the car today is really inconvenient.

This is quite common in formal English, and it is a perfectly natural form to use in writing; as such, I would advise you to use this construction in your case and write:

> Sending separate mails will look more genuine than *my* **writing** on behalf of everyone.

However, in less formal English—both written and spoken—it is more common to simply use the *object form* of the subject; that is, the object/accusative case of personal pronouns, or with other subjects, just use the subject on its own:

> He doesn’t like *me* **singing** so loudly all the time.
>   *Peter* **taking** the car today is really inconvenient.

This construction is also perfectly valid, though it is marked as being less formal. If you are writing in a generally informal, colloquial style, you can use this just fine.

You ***cannot*** use the nominative form of a personal pronoun as the subject of a gerund, though:

> <s>He doesn’t like *I* **singing** so loudly all the time.</s>

This is completely ungrammatical in *any* register of English.

---

In brief, you have two options:

> Sending separate mails will look more genuine than *my* **writing** on behalf of everyone. *(More formal)*
>   Sending separate mails will look more genuine than *me* **writing** on behalf of everyone. *(Less formal)*

Answer (score 0):

"Sending separate mails will look more genuine than me writing on behalf of everyone."

Comment: .... and "why?"

Comment: To this answer's defense, it is a) correct, and b) "why" is a very strange question to ask in the first place. There *is* no why. The only reason *me* is correct and *I* is not is because everyone uses *me* but no one uses *I*. In short: just because.

Answer (score 0):

> Sending separate mails will look more genuine than me/I writing on behalf of everyone.

*Separate*, I would change to *individual*

*Mails*, I would change to *letters*

*Look*, I would change to *seem*

And *I/me* to *my*

> Sending individual letters will seem more genuine than my writing on behalf of everyone.

Comment: This is the answer to a different question. Please answer the original question, you can edit your post and to make it more complete, and therefore more helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**me** - because  (Hello) it is/was me (who is/was sending these e-mails.)

Comment: That is a completely different and totally unrelated construction. You cannot extrapolate anything from it.